# How to get the first letter of an XML attribute with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this `XML`:

```
<entry>
  <title handle="foo">Foo</title>
</entry>
```

How can I get the first letter of the `handle` attribute using `XSLT 1.0`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`substring`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) XPath function.

For example, the following XPath expression will evaluate to 'f' for your example XML.

```
substring(/entry/title/@handle, 1, 1)
```